# IMPORTXML in Google Sheets returns N/D when I make slightly complex requests

Tags: xpath

while the xpather gives the expected values( http://xpather.com/t7HX6Fnw ) if I make the same request in Google Sheets ("//TMC/@DE") the answer is empty. 
Sheets query works only with simple un-nested path (e.g. "//@DE"). Opera user here. 
Thanks in advance.e.g.

Comment: You have a default namespace declaration with `http://traffic.nokia.com/trafficml-flow-3.2` URI

Comment: why is the namespace declaration a problem for Google Sheets when querying //TMC/@DE and it is not a problem when querying //@DE? Why has the namespace any importance for Google Sheets and not for xpather?

Comment: Because `//TMC` XPath expression means _"any `TMC` element under empty namespace URI"_

Comment: Therefore I see that  xpather (in the example I posted) and GSheets import work differently, since with xpather //TMC/@DE works fine with "any TMC element under that same namespace".

Comment: As you might see in many, many answer, XPath tester is one of the most online tools used to share XPath expression. In short, check [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/527ae5d7da1e7aeb89d0bd5b6a0258a5) how your XPath expression is wrong as in it doesn't select what you want. "XPather" is broken.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Alejandro. Now it's clear to me.